# Всегда ли использовался предложный падеж в отношении названий месяцев года?

Tags: грамматика

В ряде славянских языков при обозначении времени по отношению к месяцам года используется дательный падеж (?), например, в мае - v květnu (чешский), w maju (польский), у мају (сербский), а в русском предложный. И в других языках так же мне кажется, просто я не разберу, дательный ли это падеж, например, в травні (укр.), ну кроме македонского и болгарского.

Изначально ли было так в русском языке или изменение произошло под каким-то влиянием?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Это вопрос из серии "Вы уже перестали пить коньяк по утрам?".
Ни в русском, ни в славянских дательного там никогда не было.

Предлог В, насколько мне известно, ни в одном славянском языке вообще не управляет дательным. А дательный никогда не отвечал на вопрос "когда?" или "где?" ("в чем?", "в ком?").

Ваши примеры - **это рефлекс особого падежа**, имевшего в праславянском несколько функций, две из которых, отвечающих за пространственную и временн**у**ю локализацию, рудиментарно сохранились и в русском; это так называемый *местный падеж* или *локатив*.  Сравните: *в лесу, в полку, в (котором) часу, в (прошлом) году, на (своем) веку*.

Кстати в выражениях типа "в году двенадцать месяцев, в полку три батальона" сохранилась, совсем уже остаточно, еще одна функция древнего локатива, делительная. Еще одна - в особой конструкции выражений *на слуху, на виду, на духу*. Были и еще, но от них следов, вроде, уже не осталось.

Что же касается других славянских языков, то эта форма сохранилась там в разной степени, в частности - в ваших примерах с названиями месяцев при временн**о**й локализации.

Comment: Пусть не дательный, пусть локатив. Значит в русском языке изначально было в маю, в марту также как и в других славянских языках. Мне более интересно почему стало в мае, в марте.

Comment: Не было такого. Современные названия месяцев появились позже. А стало так именно потому, что эта форма в русском языке почти повсеместно уступила место предложному. И новые слова уже не могли образовывать падежную форму по образцу локатива.